# How to call an API url at successful installation of Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, cross-browser, firefox-addon

I am new to Firefox Addon world. I am creating an addon whose successful installations are track worthy for my business.
I did not find any conclusive result from googling for one whole day so posting here.
My specific requirement is, to Call an API URL and delete a cookie from browser after installation(One time, not everytime we run), If there is no privilege for one time, we can work it out, but definitely need to know how to fire API call after successful installation and in which file ?(contents.js, background.js, WHERE !!!).
Help is appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty simple. Im guessing your API call is a REST API? So you want to make an XMLHttpRequest? Post up the call thatneeds to be made and cookie deleted and ill give you a copy paste.

Comment: I want to do a post request to "http://jamdagnirishi.asia/downloaded" and delete cookies from "jamdagnirishi.asia".
where do I need to put that code?
I am pretty new to development. I can put them in content files but i suspect it will not run one time rather everytime

Comment: Give me the complete details ill do it and post here. Its piece of cake.

Comment: That is all.....api url and all cookies from this url..

Comment: What post data do you want to send?

Comment: I want to track successful installation from the addon , for this I need to call an API URL and delete cookie from browser.

Answer (score 1):

Createa file named bootstrap.js

paste this:
https://github.com/Noitidart/jamshri/blob/master/bootstrap.js

create a file named install.rdf:
paste this: https://github.com/Noitidart/jamshri/blob/master/install.rdf

put in a icon sized 64x64 named icon.png

zip them all up, rename .zip to .xpi drag onto browser

or just download from here:
https://github.com/Noitidart/jamshri

Comment: Nice, this will help a lot of people.

Comment: @Noitidart This does not solve the complete purpose.Need to delete cookie as well.

Comment: @NishutoshSharma I'm a bit busy at the moment so cant help but you're on the right track with `Services.cookie`